# Counting only "longest" occurrence of an N-gram using countVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I want to use a pre-defined vocabulary/lexicon from Picault & Renault (link to public CSV file [here](https://stackoverflow.com)) and fit it to sklearn's countVectorizer to eventually transform my own corpus of words into a count matrix. However, as the lexicon includes up to 9 n-grams, I only want CountVectorizer to count the highest occurrence of the sequence of n-grams. As can be seen in the CSV file, it contains the sequential n-grams and a column with the *n* of the corresponding n-gram, but no grouping variable that groups the set of n-grams together.

So as a min. ReprEx, I define the vocabulary and my corpus as follows:

```
my_vocab = [
'ab',
'ab market',
'ab market enhanc',
'ab market enhanc function',
'about',
'about econom']

my_corpus = ['ab market enhanc','ab','about econom']
```

Then define the countVectorizer and use it to transform my corpus:

```
my_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=my_vocab, ngram_range=(1,4))

my_transformed_corpus = my_vectorizer.transform(my_corpus)
print(my_transformed_corpus)
```

Current output:

```
 (0, 0) 1
 (0, 1) 1
 (0, 2) 1
 (1, 0) 1
 (2, 4) 1
 (2, 5) 1
```

Desired output:

```
 (0, 0) 1
 (0, 1) 0
 (0, 2) 1
 (1, 0) 1
 (2, 4) 0
 (2, 5) 1
```

As my actual corpus and resulting sparse matrix is quite large, I figure I'd ideally need a solution that doesn't require iterating over the sparse matrix. But since it is a one-off computation only, I wouldn't mind if that is the only/easiest solution.

**Important note:** *not every sequence of n-grams in the lexicon has a length of 9, but may be shorter (but may only be up to and including 9)*